# Raise warning or error message when user inputing employee that is already exist (Odoo)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

How do I to prevent users inputing employee that is already exist like in this picture :
[image: here]

So when the users are trying to input same employee that already exist, it will raise warning or error messages

I've made this function :

```
class overtime(models.Model):
    _name = 'overtime.overtime'

    employee_ids = fields.One2many('overtime.overtime_details', 'overtime_id', string="Employee", readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})

class overtime_details(models.Model):
    _name='overtime.overtime_details'

     @api.multi
     @api.constrains('employee_id')
     @api.onchange('employee_id')
     def prevent_duplicate(self):
        #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        if self.employee_id:
            bruh = self.search([])
            for empy in bruh:
                if self.employee_id.id == empy.employee_id.id:
                    raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),_('You Cant Enter Same Employee in One Overtime Request!'))

     nik = fields.Char('NIK', size=250, required=True)
     overtime_id = fields.Many2one('overtime.overtime', string="Overtime", ondelete='cascade')
     job_id = fields.Many2one('hr.job', string="Position", readonly=True)
     employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', "Employee", required=True, select=True, copy=False
                    , domain="[('department_id', '=', parent.department_id)]")
     ovrtm = fields.Float(compute=attd_check, string='Overtime Hour(s)')
     ttalmtp = fields.Float(compute=overtype_count, string='Total Multiplier')
```

but it loop every record that ive saved in the database, so i need help what should i do, if i want to loop record that ive input in that session? iam working on odoo v8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i'm giving to possiblities by method or by catching a constrains database error:

```py
class overtime(models.Model):
    _name = 'overtime.overtime'

    employee_ids = fields.One2many('overtime.overtime_details',
                    'overtime_id', string="Employee",
                    readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})

    #no need for multi because by default they are multi
    @api.onechange('employee_ids')
    @api.constrains('employee_ids') 
    def prevent_dupe(self): 
        # what you did here is wrong 
        # it will always give you = 12 because you are
        # computing the len of string 'employee_ids' not 
        # the number of record in the one2many field
        # o2m_size = len('employee_ids') 
        o2m_size = len(self.employee_ids) 
        employee_count = len(self.employee_ids.mapped('employee_id'))
        if o2m_size != employee_count:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(_("Employee already exist!"))


class overtime_details(models.Model):
    _name='overtime.overtime_details'

     nik = fields.Char('NIK', size=250, required=True)
     overtime_id = fields.Many2one('overtime.overtime', string="Overtime", ondelete='cascade')
     job_id = fields.Many2one('hr.job', string="Position", readonly=True)
     employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', "Employee", required=True, select=True, copy=False
                    , domain="[('department_id', '=', parent.department_id)]")
     ovrtm = fields.Float(compute=attd_check, string='Overtime Hour(s)')
     ttalmtp = fields.Float(compute=overtype_count, string='Total Multiplier')

     # if you want to prevent duplicated 
     # and constrains for that if the method didn't work for you
     _sql_constraints = [('unique_imployee_overtime', 'unique(overtime_id,employee_id)',
                                _(" Deplicated employee in overtime ")), ]
```

Comment: do you mean by the latest version is from ver 10 ? iam asking this cus iam working on v8, will it work ?

Comment: No i think it will work , with api.constrains should work for sure did you try it

Comment: sorry for late respond, it doesnt work. everytime i was inputing and deleting new record it raised the error message even there is no duplicated records. and it didnt prevent duplicating records

Comment: Can you put the name of the field and the method because it's working fine for me

Comment: `@api.onchange('employee_ids')
 @api.constrains('employee_ids')
 def prevent_dupe(self):
  o2m_size = len('employee_ids')
  employee_count = len(self.employee_ids.mapped('employee_id'))
  if o2m_size != employee_count:
   warning = {
    'title':_('Duplicated Employee'),
    'message':_('Employee already exist!')
   }
   return {'warning': warning}`

here, ive edited my question with more details

Comment: hope this will help you

Comment: ah sorry my bad, srry for my carelessness. it works perfectly, thanks alot for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a *'browse'*, instead of a *'search'*, using the inserted *'id'* as parameter and check the recordset obtained, if it is not empty raise the exception.

Something like this:

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('employee_id')
@api.onchange('employee_id')
def prevent_duplicate(self):
    if self.employee_id:
        bruh = self.search([('employee_id', '=', self.employee_id.id)])
        if len(bruh):
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),_('You Cant Enter Same Employee in One Overtime Request!'))
```

Comment: ive tried it, the warning raised even when there is no recordset that already exist

`@api.multi
@api.constrains('employee_id')
@api.onchange('employee_id')
def prevent_duplicate(self):
 #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
 if self.employee_id:
  bruh = self.browse([self.employee_id.id])
  for empy in bruh:   
   if len(bruh):
    raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),_('You Cant Enter Same Employee in One Overtime Request!'))`

Comment: Why are you cycling over *'bruh'*? Try remove the *'for empy in bruh'*. The *'browse'* gives you a recordset, which will be empty if there are no records with that *'id'*, otherwise it will be of length one. That's why I used the *'len(bruh)'*, but you need to do that outside the *'for'*, just as I wrote above.

Comment: ive tried it without `for empy in bruh` too and it was same

Comment: My fault, the *'browse'* is for the id of the current model. To search the record existence of other models you have to perform the *'search'* if you have the relation field in the current model, the case I guess we are in, otherwise perform the browse but redirecting the query to the wanted model, like: self.env[' < the emplyee model > '].browse([ < id > ]). 
I edit my answer.

Comment: it works but `bruh` keep gives me empty recordset, and still could be duplicated. and yeah we are inside of the model

Comment: Ok, so try with the *'browse'* on the *employee* model. Something like: self.env[' < the employee model > '].browse([self.employee_id.id])

Comment: i've tried use `self.env['hr.employee']` with browse and search too , and the result same like the 1st attempt. it raised the warning even there is no duplicated record

Comment: Explain the hierarchy of the relation between your model and *hr.employee*, please.

Comment: My model relation with hr.employee connected by employee_id as many2one field in my model

Comment: if you mean create my records manually by user not a function, yes.